# Jmeter - how to return value in jmeter to HTTPS request

Tags: performance, unit-testing, testing, jmeter, automated-tests

I was using JSR223 preprocessor and passing value to it's main request but value is not being return in that request.

How do I pass the value in the HTTPS request extracting from JSR223 preprocessor. In more I need to do parametrization. I am calling NodeJS code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance in order to save the generated encoded value into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

i.e. in the last line of your script do something like

```
vars.put('password', response)
```

and in the HTTP Request sampler's request body use something like:

```
"password":"${password}"
```

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: Thank you, It works fine now with your suggestion.